# git: How do I revert all files where the only change is a modified timestamp?

Tags: git, timestamp, git-revert

I have a lots of modified files in a git repo.

I need to prune the ones where there is no change, where only the timestamp has changed. Due to the amount of files it would take me a loong time to do that manually.

Is there some smart way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[A timestamp change alone should not register](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14887995/6309) in a `git status`.

That means a `git add` would only add files with actual changes.

Maybe the file permissions have changed though.

This is more likely to be related to an automatic eol conversion (end of line)

[Since Git 2.8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35204436/6309), you can quickly check that with:

```
git ls-files --eol
```

Comment: It does however. And git gui says: "The modification data of this file has been changed by another application, but the content within was not changed."

Comment: @Invariant37 what git status return?

Comment: Git status also shows those files with only modified modification date.

Comment: @Invariant37 is there a message returned by git status which indicates that only the timestamp has changed?

Comment: No, it just list those files among the files which content actually was changed.

Comment: @Invariant37 OK. See my edited answer (which refers now to http://stackoverflow.com/q/5787937/6309) and check (if you have Git 2.8 or more) the result of `git ls-files --eol` (as I detail in http://stackoverflow.com/a/35204436/6309)

Comment: @Invariant37 Then try and clone again your repo after a `git config --global core.autocrlf false`. See if you have as many files listed by a git status then.

Comment: @Invariant37 Great! Don't forget to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer and http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote